# Axis Fault after request from SoapUI

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

I am sending a request from SoapUI and I am getting an error in return.
I have no idea how to resolve this.

**Request**:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/services/ApiService/ HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml" 
Content-Length: 345
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
Response:
HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error
Set-Cookie: EZSESSIONID=y4k1kp87msmg5ni4migdd65f;Path=/
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=MIMEBoundaryurn_uuid_89EA7A7AB1A241D9571457445576391; type="application/xop+xml"; start="<0.urn:uuid:89EA7A7AB1A241D9571457445576392@apache.org>"; start-info="text/xml"
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(7.6.3.v20120416)

--MIMEBoundaryurn_uuid_89EA7A7AB1A241D9571457445576391
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <0.urn:uuid:89EA7A7AB1A241D9571457445576392@apache.org>

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode><faultstring>org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMTextImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement</faultstring><detail /></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
--MIMEBoundaryurn_uuid_89EA7A7AB1A241D9571457445576391--
```

**ServerLog**:

> ERROR 2016-03-08 19:29:36.133 AxisEngine [request-19]
>   org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMTextImpl cannot be cast to
>   org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement org.apache.axis2.AxisFault:
>   org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMTextImpl cannot be cast to
>   org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement     at
>   org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
>   ~[axis2-kernel-1.4.1.jar:na]